# Unable to convert from string to datetime C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse a string to Datetime, but it is not working and giving an error:

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

The string is perfect.

Here is the code:

```
string deliv = DeliveryDateTextBox.Text;

string[] delivday = deliv.Split('-');
int year, month, day;

int.TryParse(delivday[0], out day);
int.TryParse(delivday[1], out month);
int.TryParse(delivday[2], out year);

string dtt = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

DateTime datet = DateTime.ParseExact(dtt, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

jobcard.DeliveryDate = datet;
```

I debugged the code and it is giving `{01-01-0001 12:00:00 AM}` on `datet`.

Comment: *The string is perfect* can you post an example of the string

Comment: What is the value of deliv at the start

Comment: If `day`, `month` and `year` are all correct, then you don't need to do any further parsing - you can just create the `DateTime` using `new DateTime(year, month, day)`

Comment: @MatthewWatson post it as answer

Comment: Although it would be simpler to use `DateTime.ParseExact("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead of splitting to start with, IMO.

Comment: "I debugged the code and it is giving {01-01-0001 12:00:00 AM} on datet" - if `ParseExact` is throwing an exception, you're not assigning *any* value to it.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your input `string deliv`

Comment: thanks Matthew Watson... Its working perfectly :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides the fact that you *should* be using `new DateTime(year, month, day)`, or even `DateTime.TryParseExact(deliv, "d-M-yyyy", .... )` on the original string...

Your call to `DateTime.ParseExact()` is failing because your input string has single-digit **`day`** and/or single-digit **`month`**, while your pattern `dd/MM/yyyy` demands double digits for both.

This can be fixed by using `d/M/yyyy` for the pattern, it will accept single and double digits. But please don't, see the first paragraph!

Comment: While this answer will solve the immediate problem, I can't agree with it - since it's still keeping the basic problem of manually parsing the string, when the framework provides a TryParseExact method.

Comment: Please, add Can be fixed also by: string dtt = $"{day:D2}/{month:D2}/{year:D4}";

Comment: Note that the date to be parsed uses `-` not `/`

Comment: @DavidG dtt has slashes, deliv has dashes, I think my answer accounts for both?

Comment: Yes but why bother with `dtt` at all, just go straight from `deliv` to the date.

Comment: It's in my first paragraph already, the rest is to explain what caused the parse issue.

Comment: Working :) Thankyou @PeterB

Answer (score 1):

You over complicated things in this code.
Manually parsing the string to extract int values of day, month and year just to recombine them into a new string and parsing it makes no sense.

Simply try to parse the original string:

```
DateTime datet;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(
   DeliveryDateTextBox.Text, 
   "dd-MM-yyyy", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   DateTimeStyles.None, out datet))
{
    // string was successfully parsed to dateTime.
}
```

Comment: Dear downvoter: Do you think this answer is wrong? If so, why? Please leave a comment when downvoting so that we can learn from it.

Comment: This is in my opinion the right solution, except that if this is user input I would use the format "d-M-yyyy" in order not to require the user to use leading zero in one digit days and months

Comment: @JeppeAlkærsig Thanks. however I think Christopher's answer is better - Simply don't use a textbox to get a date value from the user - use a datePicker instead...

Answer (score 1):

There is no "perfect" DateTime String. How you can can/should represent a DateTime is dependent 100% on the CultureFormat of Windows, which can be totally different even within a langauge: For example en-gb and en-us disagree on what the decimal, thousand seperator are and in which order the date components should be listed.

Your whole code does not make a lot of sense. It seems you have some disjointed textboxes where the user inputs the day, month and year seperately. Then you parse them to int. Then you turn them into a string. Then you try to parse the string.

And at no point do you even **check** if the original user inputs are valid. That original parsing to Int might already fail. So you might try to parse 0/0/0 into a DateTime. To which your output is actually the perfect answer. And then there is stuff like anything before 1800 or so being literally not on the Gregorian calendar.

If you want the user to input a date, use a DatePicker element. Every GUI technology I know of has one. They give you DateTimes as return value. Do not try your custom workaround.

Comment: Just an fyi: there isn't disagreement with respect to the decimal / thousand separators between the UK and US.

Comment: @john: Oh, I was certain en-uk used the European style (comma as decmal, point as thousand seperator). Looks like I was wrong.